# Change message "Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)" in IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6

How do I change the message `Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)` in IIS 6? I would like to be able to change it to `Bad Request (Invalid Hostname - SERVERNAME)` so I can identify which server gets the request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying "which server" in the context of a cluster or something?  Or are you instead looking to see what the bad Host: header value is?

Invalid Hostname means that you don't have a website on the server configured to handle requests for whatever host was sent in the Host: header of the http request.

That means that your server (call it SERVERA) is getting a request that looks something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Connection: close
...
```

and you have a DNS record for myserver.com that points to the IP of the SERVERA (so that the request will actually make it to SERVERA).  But what you don't have is a web site configured in IIS on SERVERA that is set to accept requests for myserver.com.

Comment: @squillman This is in the context of routing problems at the hosting company. I want to know which physical server responded to this request with an Invalid hostname. In other words my A record is correct, but I don't trust how the hosting company is doing the routing.

So I would like to verify that my server is actually getting the request.

Comment: @Keltex: ah, ok.  In that case can you not just look at the IIS log to see if your requests are getting to the server?  It sounds like you have physical access to the server, in that you're wondering how to modify IIS config.